# How to construct moving time average with different weights for different months?

Tags: matlab, filtering

So I want to construct a moving time average with different weights for different months. E.g. see the filter function at http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/data_analysis/filtering-data.html, where b = # of days in each month and a = # of days in a year.

The issue is, though, that the time-series is a series of temperatures for every month (and I want to construct a yearly average temperature for each set of possible years, where a year could be from March to February, for example). Using this approach, the first month in each window would be weighted as 31/365, irrespective of whether the first month is January or June.

In that case, the standard filter algorithm wouldn't work. Is there an alternative?

A solution that incorporates leap years would also be nice, but is not necessary for an initial solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A weighted average is defined as `sum(x .* weights) / sum(weights)`. If you want to calculate this in a moving average kind of way, I guess you could do (untested):

```
moving_sum = @(n, x) filter(ones(1,n), 1, x);
moving_weighted_avg = moving_sum(12, temperature .* days_per_month) ...
    ./ moving_sum(12, days_per_month);
```

If `temperature` is a vector of monthly temperatures and `days_per_month` contains the actual number of days of the corresponding months, this should even work in case of leap years.

**Edit to answer comment**

You can reconstruct `days_per_month` like so:

```
start_year = 2003;
start_month = 10;
nmonth = 130;
month_offset = 0:nmonth - 1;

month = mod(start_month + month_offset - 1, 12) + 1;
year = start_year + floor((start_month + month_offset - 1) / 12);
days_in_month = eomday(year, month);

disp([month_offset; year; month; days_in_month]') %print table to check
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the idea! :) I've just tried implementing it.. But what if temperature is a vector of size 130? Then it can't multiply days_per_month (which is a vector of size 12).

Comment: though alternatively i could maybe try a repmat(days_per_month,1,# of years in dataset)

Comment: I edited the answer to show how to recover `days_per_month`, given the starting month of your measurements. Please mark the answer accepted if it works for you ...